# Cómo mostrar el total de votos para cada candidato - Java

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de java en donde estoy atascado en cada vez que se introduce un voto debo buscar la manera de incrementar el contador correspondiente de ese candidato, a continuación os dejo el enunciado para que se vea más claro.

> Programa que permite realizar el recuento de votos en unas elecciones.
> El programa pide el número de candidatos y el número de votantes.
> Luego pregunta a cada votante a que candidato vota.
> Al final muestra el total de votos para cada candidato.
> No es necesario almacenar todos los votos, solo irlos contando.
> Utilizar un array de contadores. Cada vez que se introduce un voto se incrementa el
> contador correspondiente.
> Validar cualquier posible error al votar.

Hasta ahora tengo el siguiente código:

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Entra número de candidatos: ");
    int num_candidatos = teclado.nextInt(); //Aquí especifico el espacio de la array candidatos

    System.out.println("Entra número de votantes:");
    int total_votantes = teclado.nextInt(); //Aquí especifico el espacio de la array votos

    int voto_user; //Voto de cada user

    int[] candidatos = new int[num_candidatos]; // Num de Candidatos 

    int[] votos = new int[total_votantes]; // Num de personas que votan 

    
    for (int i = 0; i <= candidatos.length; i++) {

        do {
            int indice = i+1;
            System.out.println("Votante " + indice + ", entra tu voto (1-" + num_candidatos + "):");
            
            // Aquí tenemos el voto del votante
            voto_user = teclado.nextInt();

            if (voto_user > num_candidatos) {
                System.out.println("Voto inválido.");
            }

        } while (voto_user > num_candidatos);

        // Si el voto es valido lo guardamos en la posición que le toque
        votos[i] = voto_user;
    }
    System.out.println("Resultados:");
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < candidatos.length; i++) {
        
        System.out.println("Candidato " + (i+1) + " "+votos[i] + " votos.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He hecho un par de modificaciones. La primera, en el bucle for, tienes que comparar con la variable "votos" en lugar de candidatos, ya que tienes que recoger un voto por votante, y no por candidato. Esta comparación, en lugar de hacerla con <= la hacemos solo con <, ya que el indice empieza en 0, y si tienes 4 votantes, irias desde 0 hasta 4, o sea, darias 5 vueltas en lugar de 4 como quieres. También puedes inicializar i=1 y dejarlo como <=, y te ahorras el uso de tu variable indice.
Por otro lado, cada voto sumo 1 al candidato (cogiendo como posición del array el voto en si, bueno, el voto -1, porque el array inicia en la posición 0, y no en la 1). Luego al imprimir, solo tienes que imprimir el valor dentro de la posición de cada candidato para saber la cantidad de votos que tiene cada uno.
No se si está del todo bien explicado, cualquier duda me avisas.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Entra número de candidatos: ");
    int num_candidatos = teclado.nextInt(); //Aquí especifico el espacio de la array candidatos

    System.out.println("Entra número de votantes:");
    int total_votantes = teclado.nextInt(); //Aquí especifico el espacio de la array votos

    int voto_user; //Voto de cada user

    int[] candidatos = new int[num_candidatos]; // Num de Candidatos

    int[] votos = new int[total_votantes]; // Num de personas que votan


    for (int i = 0; i < votos.length; i++) { //tienes que compararlo con el numero de votantes, para que repita la accion esa cantidad de veces

        do {
            int indice = i + 1;
            System.out.println("Votante " + indice + ", entra tu voto (1-" + num_candidatos + "):");

            // Aquí tenemos el voto del votante
            voto_user = teclado.nextInt();

            if (voto_user > num_candidatos) {
                System.out.println("Voto inválido.");
            }
            else {
                candidatos[voto_user-1]++;
            }
        } while (voto_user > num_candidatos);
    }
    System.out.println("Resultados:");
    System.out.println("-----------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < candidatos.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Candidato " + (i + 1) + " " + candidatos[i] + " votos.");
    }
}
```